# Running LED strip lights

Tags: led

Hi all I'm in a bit of a pickle
I bought a couple of rolls of 5m 5050 DC12V 60LEDs/m in warm white colour for a home project..... The only problem is that when they arrived they didn't come with anything else, no power supply, no adaptors of any kind, no transformers just the two rolls of lights.
My qusetion is can I run these lights on a normal 12v charger, multi voltage adaptor or do I need to buy the proper transformers/adaptors to power these.
Thanks in advance for any help/ advice that can be given

Comment: Can you share details of the strips? The critical information is the required amperage. With that, you can choose the appropriate 12v transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Typical 5050 LEDs are rated at 0.24 Watts per LED.

At 60 LEDs per metre, your 5 metre strip has 300 LEDs requiring at least 300 x 0.24 = 72 Watts.

At 12 Volts, a 72 Watt load draws 72 / 12 = 6 Amps.

I would obtain a 12 Volt power supply that is rated for at least 100 Watts (8 or 9 amps).

Comment: Not my usual approach but you nailed the numbers dead solid perfect.  Refreshing to see people actually grok these rather neat products.  To go into more detail, it's 0.08W per LED per channel, and a 5050 has 3 channels.  You can use that for dim/bright, for instance.